# Multiple where clauses as dataset filters in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm creating an SSRS report using the SQL query below as a single Dataset for the report.  As you can see I have different Where clauses, these would be used depending upon which Parameter dropdown is selected when running the report.  If I only needed to pass a single value to a single where I could just use the selected value of the dropdown.  However, it seems like I need to pass a dummy value from the dropdown and then based on that selection, do a filter Switch statement and determine which where clause to use.  Can I pass a SQL string to my dataset based upon which dropdown is selected?  What other ways can I accomplish this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    cip.CaseID
   ,cip.ProsNum AS FileNum
   ,cip.CaseInvPersLastName + ', ' + cip.CaseInvPersFirstName AS Attorney
   ,c.CaseStatusCode
   ,c.CaseStatusDesc
   ,dbo.ConvertTimeToClientTimeZone(ce.EventDT) AS OpenDate
   ,cip2.CaseInvPersLastName AS Respondent
   ,j.Dispo
   ,cd.Description AS DispoDesc
FROM jw50_Case c
INNER JOIN jw50_CaseInvPers cip
    ON cip.CaseID = c.CaseID AND cip.InvolveTypeCode = 'CP007' AND cip.CaseInvPersActive = 1
INNER JOIN jw50_CaseInvPers cip2
    ON cip2.CaseID = c.CaseID AND cip2.InvolveTypeCode = 'CP001' AND cip2.CaseInvPersActive = 1
INNER JOIN jw50_CaseEvent ce
    ON ce.EventID = (SELECT TOP 1 EventID FROM jw50_CaseEvent WHERE CaseID = cip.CaseID ORDER BY EventDT)
LEFT JOIN devJudgement j
    ON j.CaseID = cip.CaseID
LEFT JOIN devCountDispo cd
    ON cd.Code = j.Dispo

-- Sent to screening
--WHERE c.CaseStatusCode = 'CS007'

-- Closed
WHERE c.caseStatusCode = 'CS006' AND j.Dispo IN ('CD002','CD003') AND c.CaseTypeCode = 'TY001'

-- Closed - Info Only
--WHERE c.caseStatusCode = 'CS006' AND j.Dispo IN ('CD001') AND c.CaseTypeCode = 'TY001'

-- Reopened
--WHERE c.caseStatusCode = 'CS008' AND c.CaseTypeCode = 'TY001'

-- Under appeal
--WHERE c.caseStatusCode = 'CS009' AND c.CaseTypeCode = 'TY001'

    AND ce.EventDT >= @startDate AND ce.EventDT < @endDate + 1

Order BY cip.ProsNum
```

Please provide any assistance.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parenthesis to create groups of criteria along with `OR`, so that for any value of your passed variable you can use one query and the proper `WHERE` criteria will get used, something like:

```
  WHERE ((@variable = 1 AND c.CaseStatusCode = 'CS007')
         OR  (@variable = 2 AND c.caseStatusCode = 'CS006' AND j.Dispo IN ('CD002','CD003') AND c.CaseTypeCode = 'TY001')
         OR  (@variable = 3 AND  c.caseStatusCode = 'CS006' AND j.Dispo IN ('CD001') AND c.CaseTypeCode = 'TY001')
         OR  (@variable = 4 AND c.caseStatusCode = 'CS008' AND c.CaseTypeCode = 'TY001')
         OR  (@variable = 5 AND c.caseStatusCode = 'CS009' AND c.CaseTypeCode = 'TY001'))      
    AND ce.EventDT >= @startDate AND ce.EventDT < @endDate + 1
```

In the above situation, one of the `@variable = n` criteria must be met, AND the bottom line with the date criteria, adjust as needed.

Comment: That works most excellent!  I was looking at doing something like that in the filter expression but it felt dirty.  This way all I do is pass a value to the query and all the work is done on the SQL server.  Thank you.